# CSS ellipsis inside flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I have a layout based on flexbox. Two columns, one fixed size and the second need to take the rest space. In the grow column I have a string that I want it to be clipped.

In Chrome it works fine. But it doesn't work in Firefox and IE. I tried to fix it by giving the grow (flex item) inner element a width by using relative and absolute positions, but then I got a corrupt layout. The corruption is related that the element's height doesn't take in account to all its child elements.

Note: the inner element inside the flex grow item is built with several **div** tags.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amosnesher/ztc9454w/).

```css
.cols {
  display: flex;
}

.flex--0 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.width--100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<h1>Ellipsis inside Flex item</h1>

<h2>Working fine in Chrome Not working in FF and IE</h2>

<div class="cols border">
  <div class="flex--0 border padding--sm">Icon</div>
  <div class="flex--1 border padding--sm">
    <div class="ellipsis">Icon lkdjasdoif dlkjasdfo;isd fasldf ;asofj as;doifja dflkas d;laiksjdf oaisjdf asldkfj a;slkfdj as;oifj as;ldkfj asldkfjowiejfa;wlkdfj as;lkdjf as;lkdfj a;osifj aw;lkefj asldkfj ;aolifj aw;oiefjasl;dkfj a;slkdfj aodfj aw;lfjk as;lkdfj a;oiwefjr</div>
    <div>Icon</div>
    <div>Icon</div>
    <div>Icon</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Second BLOCK</div>

<h2>Trying to fix in FF and IE (Layout corrupts)</h2>
<div class="cols border">
  <div class="flex--0 border padding--sm">Icon</div>
  <div class="flex--1 relative border padding--sm">
    <div class="absolute width--100">
      <div class="ellipsis">Icon lkdjasdoif dlkjasdfo;isd fasldf ;asofj as;doifja dflkas d;laiksjdf oaisjdf asldkfj a;slkfdj as;oifj as;ldkfj asldkfjowiejfa;wlkdfj as;lkdjf as;lkdfj a;osifj aw;lkefj asldkfj ;aolifj aw;oiefjasl;dkfj a;slkdfj aodfj aw;lfjk as;lkdfj a;oiwefjr</div>
      <div>Icon</div>
      <div>Icon</div>
      <div>Icon</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>Second BLOCK</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add `min-width: 0;` to the flex item.

```
.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60x4bfp1/)**

Or add `overflow: hidden;` to it.

```
.flex--1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden; /*or auto*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk6qhy64/)**

---

**Why?**

> [4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of the
>   `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1.

---

Alternatively, you can wrap the content into a container.

```
.container {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLp8jop0/)**

Comment: Thanks. It indeed working in IE and FF. Can you explain why it need this kind of workaround? I would expected to work at first place....

Comment: Ran into this when updating to chrome 48. This workaround seems to have fixed it. Many thanks.